# How can I access the selected element of a combobox in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, combobox

I put an array into a combobox and want to delete the marked element (selected via click on element in combobox) when pressing a button. How can i access the selected element?

my html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select size="5">
    <option ng-repeat="element in elements">{{element}}</option>    
</select>
<button ng-click="removeSelected()">Delete selected</button>
```

my js:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.elements = [1, 2, 3];
    $scope.removeSelected = function () {};
}
```

Here's my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TipNo1/r3603Lch/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of `ng-repeat`.

`ng-options` is a directive which is applied to the parent select element, like so:

```
<select ng-options="element for element in elements" ng-model="selected">
</select>
```

You can then go ahead and access the active selection through the `ng-model` of the select element, which in this case is `selected` - and remove it like so:

```
$scope.removeSelected = function(){
    var index = $scope.elements.indexOf($scope.selected);
    $scope.elements.splice(index, 1)
};
```

[Updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/r3603Lch/1/)